# Dynamic Admin Custom Fields Don't Save When Click Save Config Button

Tags: system.xml

**I Create Dynamic Table In Admin Panel, Each Row Contain 5 Fields** That Will Be Display As Carousel In Front Page.

I Manage To Create It.

when I click Add Row Its Adding The Rows To The Table **But When I Try To Saved It (Save Config Button) Its Not Saving The Rows I Created.**

App/code/vendor/module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <tab id="kravitz" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
        <label>Kravitz</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="homeiconslider" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Icon Slider</label>
        <tab>kravitz</tab>
        <resource>Kravitz_IconSlider::config_IconSLider</resource>
        <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
            <label>General Configuration</label>
            <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Module Enable</label>
                <comment>Set To 'Yes' If You Want The Icon Slider Module To Be display At Frontend.</comment>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="display_text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Block title</label>
                <comment>This is Optional, Leave Empty If You Dont Want Any Title To Be Display On Icon Slider block.
                if Not Empty The Title will display At Frontend.</comment>

            </field>
        </group>

        <group id="iconslidersgroup" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
            <label>Icon Sliders</label>
            <field id="slideritems" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label" type="text">
                <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Config\Form\Field\Slides</frontend_model>
                <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

App/code/vendor/module/Block/Adminhtml/Config/Form/Field/Slide.php

```
<?php

 namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Config\Form\Field;

 class Slides extends AbstractFieldArray
 {
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->addColumn('label', ['label' => __('Icon Name')]);
    $this->addColumn('text', ['label' => __('ALT')]);
    $this->addColumn('link', ['label' => __('Link')]);
    $this->addColumn('image_url', ['label' => __('Image (size: 640px X 333px)'), 'style' => 'file']);
    $this->addColumn('order', ['label' => __('Order')]);

    parent::_construct();
}
 }
```

Any Idea Why It's Not Saving The Rows ?
Ty.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace this code and check :-**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Config\Form\Field;

use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;

class Slides extends AbstractFieldArray
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->addColumn('label', ['label' => __('Icon Name')]);
        $this->addColumn('text', ['label' => __('ALT')]);
        $this->addColumn('link', ['label' => __('Link')]);
        $this->addColumn('image_url', ['label' => __('Image (size: 640px X 333px)'), 'style' => 'file']);
        $this->addColumn('order', ['label' => __('Order')]);

        parent::_construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: Still Not Working My Friend

Comment: follow step like s:up and s:s:d -f and check

Comment: I did And Still No Success .
i am OverRide This File (AbstractFieldArray) With Custom File that Located In the Same Folder As  Slide.php, cus i want to add Image Upload Field To the Table.
Thats Why I dident "use" Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;

Comment: but Even If I Change It And Did Use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;
 its Still Dont Work